# How to change milisecond position of playing java clip

Tags: java

I can't change the millisecond position of currently played clip in java. I tried, but it's not working.

```
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.Clip;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Play {
     public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
          AudioInputStream input = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File("song.wav"));
          Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
          clip.open(input);
          clip.setMicrosecondPosition(1000);
          clip.start();
          new Scanner(System.in).nextLine();
     }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with `not work`?

Comment: So, what exactly is not working and how do you know that it's not working?

Comment: Not knowing clips, should `setMicrosecondPosition` be `setMillisecondPosition`?